# How to split code in React for Admin and user

Tags: reactjs, laravel, webpack

I am creating an application that will have website and three logins for different roles in react with laravel.
My concern is I don't want to expose my admin routes and increase bundle file too. So how can I do this? What will be the best approach?

I had read about dynamic imports and that solves so much thing but my routes are still in the main bundle. So how can i do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can lazy load components in React.
https://medium.com/@muratcatal/lazy-loading-in-react-2a43ea2b2dd1
https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable

You will get different bundles and based on when needed it will load those bundles.

Regarding admin routes, you need to add authentication checks in your app to make sure if someone is not logged in, route them to the sign in page.

Comment: Thanks @mukund-goel your answer is helpful. I had one solution also like to create two bundles by running different commands in node while compiling. As user will never going to visit admin part so why to show also routes of it.
So the solution I came up with create two bundles with webpack.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the solution.
My solution is to split it with webpack configuration and change in package.json. See my sample code for compiling to development

`"development": "cross-env process.env.section=frontend NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",`

"admin-development": "cross-env process.env.section=backend NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",

and in webpack check for process.env.section and according to it compile file to specific folder.